# How to access associative array in yii2

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

How to access the values in associative array in yii2. Note that this array is return by the ArrayHelper. I want to access the value of **project_id** . I tried to use getColumn($array, 'project_id') property from the ArrayHelper class. But it throws: `unidentified index project_id`.

This below shown array is dumped using VarDumper of yii2:

```
[ 
  [ 
    [ 
 'plot_id' => '9',

 'plot_no' => '4',

 'project_id' => '1', 

 'project' =>
      [ 
   'project_id' => '1',
   'project_name' => 'City Dubaiq', 

      ],
    ], 
  ], 
]
```

Comment: Well you have two instances of `project_id` in your example, and you have not specified which one you need. Do you need all `project_id` values in a given array recursively?

Comment: wow. how did they manage to actually have a worse var_dump then the very correct `var_dump()`. you don't even see the two first `[0]` keys... you should try `var_dump($array)`, you would have understood right away how to access your variable

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier who are the "they" you talk about.

Comment: The people who designed the var dumper of yii2. If you look closely, we should be seeing a nested array in which the two first level are at key 0, however we do not see the numeric keys in their var dumper (or at least in ops code)

Comment: Hi, Thanks I solved it by using ArrayHelper. First I did not use array helper instead I got results as Array().

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of `project_id` in Yii2's `ArrayHelper` like below(with your code):

```
echo \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($array[0][0], 'project_id'); //1
```